# twitter4j.auth.AccessToken instantiating in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, twitter4j

I'm working with ColdFusion 9.0.1 and latest (for current date) stable build of twitter4j library - twitter4j-core-2.2.4. I'm trying to create functionality which allows users to login or register at our site using their twitter accounts. 
I was able to create authorization part: user click on the link on our site and system redirects him to twitter page. On this page he able to "Authorise" our application. After that system redirecting him back using callBackURL. 
But I have a problem with next step. When I'm trying to setOAuthAccessToken and for that trying to instantiate AccessToken object with follow part of code:

```
accessToken = createObject( 'java', 'twitter4j.auth.AccessToken' ).init( 'myStoredRequestToken', 'myStoredRequestTokenSecret' );
```

But I have follow error:

> An exception occurred while instantiating a Java object. The class
>   must not be an interface or an abstract class. Error: ''.

Any ideas?

**Update:**

*The start part of stacktrace:*

'coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaObjectInstantiationException: Object instantiation exception. at coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaProxy.CreateObject(JavaProxy.java:171) at coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaProxy.invoke(JavaProxy.java:80) at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2360) at cftwitter2ecfc2084917956$funcGETUSERCREDENTIALS.runFunction(C:\inetpub\wwwroot_test\twPlayGrnd_com\twitter.cfc:36) at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472) at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368) at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55) at ...

*...cut here, not sure this is important...*

*the last part is*

cfapplication2ecfc665259542$funcONREQUEST.runFunction(C:\inetpub\wwwroot_test\twPlayGrnd\application.cfc:55) ... 55 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: *Invalid access token format*. at twitter4j.auth.AccessToken.(AccessToken.java:50) ... 60 more'

*I saw the message about wrong format, but based on documentation at http://twitter4j.org it should accept two agruments (strings with keys). Am I wrong?*

**Update 2**
**just find that out - I am sorry that I brought you into confusion with my first post and example... of course I used myStoredRequestToken, myStoredRequestTokenSecret, not a consumer key/secret **
*there are relevant parts of code I'm using for this functionality*

**application.cfc** *("onApplicationStart" function, instantiating components on start of application)*

```
<cffunction name="onApplicationStart" access="public" returntype="boolean" output="false">
  ...
  <cfset application.com.twitterInstance = server.javaloader.create("twitter4j.TwitterFactory").getInstance() />
  <cfset application.com.twitter = createObject("component","_com.twitter").init() />  *<!--- cfc component which will be listed below --->*
  ...
</cffunction>
```

**twitter.cfc** *(corresponding coldfusion component)*

```
<cfcomponent displayname="twitter" output="false">

  <cffunction name="init" access="public" output="false">
    <cfreturn this>
  </cffunction>     

<cffunction name="authorizeTwitter" access="public" output="false">
  <cfargument name="callBackURL" type="string" required="false" default="#request.twtCallBackURL#" /> 

    <cfset var requestToken = "" />

    <cfset application.com.twitterInstance.setOAuthConsumer(request.twtConsumerKey,request.twtConsumerSecret) />   
    <cfset requestToken = application.com.twitterInstance.getOAuthRequestToken(arguments.callBackURL) />
    <cflock scope="session" type="exclusive" timeout="10">
      <cfset session.oAuthRequestToken = requestToken.getToken()>
      <cfset session.oAuthRequestTokenSecret = requestToken.getTokenSecret()>
    </cflock>
    <cflocation url="#vLocal.requestToken.getAuthorizationURL()#" addtoken="No" />
</cffunction>


<cffunction name="getUserCredentials" access="public" output="true">
  <cfset var vLocal = {} />
  <cfset vLocal.accessToken = "" />
  <cfset vLocal.userData = "" />
  <cfset vLocal.requestToken = "" />

  <cfset vLocal.accessToken = server.javaloader.create("twitter4j.auth.AccessToken").init(session.oAuthRequestToken,session.oAuthRequestTokenSecret)>
  <cfset application.com.twitterInstance.setOAuthAccessToken(vLocal.accessToken) />
  <cfset vLocal.userData = application.com.twitterInstance.verifyCredentials() />

  <cfdump var="#vLocal.userData#" label="User Credentials">
</cffunction>
```

*First function is for first step - requesting twitter for autorization page (where user can autorize or deny application). Call back URL runs the page what calls the second function and I have problem only at this step (line for generation accessToken).*

*I have the same result if Im using createObject function instead of javaloader.*

*So, my main question is still the same - to obtain the users unique Access Token? Please point me, what I'm doing wrong? What is a correct format for unique user's accessToken generation? Should I place oauth_verifier parameter there? if so, how?*

Comment: That seems weird for sure. That argument signature matches one of the constructors for that class, and it is not an interface. Maybe try using JavaCast on the arguments to make sure they are going through as java.lang.String. Otherwise I am drawing a blank.

Comment: Post the stack trace. It contains the real (ie more detailed) error message.

Comment: @Leigh - Thanks, done. Should I post whole stacktrace? The cut part just contains the functions and templates which were run one by another.

Comment: @JasonDean thanks for idea, just tested the follow:

`accessToken = createObject( "java", "twitter4j.auth.AccessToken" ).init(javaCast("string",session.oAuthRequestToken),javaCast("string",session.oAuthRequestTokenSecret));`

but unfortunately have the same error :(

Comment: It does accept two strings, yes. But from the error anyway it sounds like it does not like the keys. Are you sure they are valid?

Comment: Well, it seems yes. I used keys as it suggested in official documentation and other resources. On first step - authorization - I stored in session two keys 
`<cfset session.oAuthRequestToken = requestToken.getToken()>
<cfset session.oAuthRequestTokenSecret = requestToken.getTokenSecret()>`
And using these keys on callBack page.

Comment: You have got me there. I only know the source says that error can occur when it cannot find a dash "-" in the `token` (ie first string).

Comment: Hmm... that's really strange. Keys are generated by dev.twitter and I didn't check it format, supposing that it is correct by default. For me it looks like UeNofdAOZDhtBoJgvDjxy3q3dAu38XglhqszwFHNuTU, the secret has the same format and no any dashes. 
Can you point me - where did you get info about dashes? twitter4j sources? (if so, for me it will be really hard to find it, I'm CF developer, not Java :((( )

Comment: I just perused the source in github. I am *not* suggesting you need to do that :) just mentioning that is where the error is coming from. Unfortunately, I am not very familiar with twitter4j. Have you had a look around S.O.? Maybe one of the threads on twitter4j/CF might offer some tips: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104243/twitter4j-jquery-coldfusion-integration/7132272#7132272

Comment: Yes, saw this post and honestly speaking looks like I dug all internet :) trying to find an answer. Unfortunately most of resources (including post which you mentioned) is showing examples for old API of twitter4j :( But my task is to use latest one :( 
However, thanks a lot for your attempts to help. I really appreciated.

Comment: @Stalker - I ran a *very* brief test in Eclipse. Everything worked okay with v2.2.4. So I am still wondering if the values passed into `AccessToken` are really correct. From what I can tell it expects the `access token/secret` values not the `consumer key/secret` (and my access token *does* contain a dash). Can you double check that you are not accidentally passing in the `consumer` values?

Comment: This may be a stupid question given the error message your receiving, but did you add your twitter4j-core-2.2.4 folder to you Colfdusion class path in CF admin?

Comment: @Bazza - Yes it is there or they would be getting a `ClassNotFoundException` instead. I am pretty sure they are just passing the wrong value into the constructor.

Comment: @Leigh - please, see my commens below. No, I'm not using consumer key/secret as access token/secret. Also please take a look on update for this post. Can you please also put an example of your code here?

Comment: @Bazza - Sure, I added it. Also I tried to use javaloader library. The same result for both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* I figured out what is wrong with the help of the examples [8. Sign in with Twitter](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html) and 
[Adding support for automated tweets with OAuth](http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2010/9/7/Adding-support-for-automated-tweets-with-OAuth). Only tested with my own account though ..

Before you redirect to the authorization page, save the whole `RequestToken` object in a session variable. You will need it to extract the AccessToken. Note: I am storing the `TwitterFactory` in the application scope - *not* the instance

```
 <cfset Twitter = application.TwitterFactory.getInstance()>
 <cfset Twitter.setOAuthConsumer(application.TwitterConsumerKey, application.TwitterConsumerSecret)>
 <cfset Session.RequestToken = Twitter.getOAuthRequestToken( YourCallBackURL )>
```

---

On callback, twitter adds a parameter named `oauth_verifier` to the URL. Use that value and the saved `RequestToken` to extract the `AccessToken`.

```
<cfset AccessToken = Twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(Session.RequestToken, URL.oauth_verifier)>
<cfset session.StoredAccessToken = AccessToken.getToken()>
<cfset session.StoredAccessSecret = AccessToken.getTokenSecret()>
```

---

Once you have the `AccessToken/Secret` you can access user details (update status,...) anywhere.

```
<cfset Twitter = application.TwitterFactory.getInstance()>
<cfset Twitter.setOAuthConsumer(application.TwitterConsumerKey,application.TwitterConsumerSecret)>
<cfset AccessToken = createObject("java", "twitter4j.auth.AccessToken")>
<cfset OAuthToken = AccessToken.init(session.StoredAccessToken, session.StoredAccessSecret)>
<cfset Twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(OAuthToken)>
<cfset userData = Twitter.verifyCredentials()>

<cfoutput>
    id = #userData.getId()#<br> 
    name = #userData.getName()#<br> 
    followers = #userData.getFollowersCount()#<br>  
    friends = #userData.getFriendsCount()#<br>  
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for continue helping :) Yes, I also figured that out and my solution is similar to code which you posted, but I wasn't able to put it here until now (it cost me many hard hours and it's early morning here). This solution is works for me perfectly, thanks!

Comment: I am glad your persistence paid off and you finally got it working :) Not sure if you saw the note about the `TwitterFactory`. I do not think the *instance* should be stored in the application scope, just the factory.

Comment: Hmm... looks like I missed that thing and yes, you are right about that too. Thanks again, Leigh :)

Answer (score 2):

You are passing consumer key/secret instead of access token/secret.
You can generate your access token/secret at dev.twitter.com.
https://dev.twitter.com/apps » create my access token

Best,
Yusuke

Comment: +1. I just figured that out! Literally two minutes before you responded :)

Comment: Thank you @Yusuke... but guys, looks like now I'm totally lost... No, I'm not using consumer key/secret as access token/secret. Honestly speaking I supposed that generation of access token on the dev.twitter.com side is only for accessing twitter for posting tweets there or something (I got only consumer key and secret from there).
But as I described I need to autentificate user on my site with twitter account and needs to get his data (name, image, nubmer of tweets, etc) So, I need to obtain the user's unique Access Token (which later will be placed in database for further using)

Comment: I used examples from different recources and assumed that I need to generate token based on request tokens, like this [link](http://www.pakzilla.com/2009/10/03/tutorial-java-based-twitter-app-on-google-app-engine/) and this [link](http://jeungun.wordpress.com/2009/09/03/quick-and-dirty-twitter4j-oauth-for-web-apps/)
I described my steps in new update of my post. Please, take a look and let me know what you think

Comment: @Stalker - Honestly .. I am a little lost myself :) While I understand the *code*, I do not have a grasp of the *api* yet. So I do not want to send you off on a "wild goose chase". I suspect Yusuke knows the api better. If he can point you to a working java example that does what you need, I can help you make it work.

Comment: @Leigh - I understand, thank you anyway. Will wait for Yusuke comment, hope he will be able to help.